Globally Install Nuget Packages
I'm currently learning Rx.NET.  I'm having to install the Nuget Package with each new project.  Is there a way to install a Nuget package once and make it available to future projects so I don't have to reinstall it every time?
Internet search and A.I. were no help.  All the examples, videos, and A.I. explained how to install Nuget for a single project.  There is no option in Nuget Package Manager to install packages globally.

You can create your own Visual Studio template that will include what you need.
Reference information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/visual-studio-templates
Additional information:
Create a Visual Studio Project Template that pulls NuGet references from online feed
Creating a Visual Studio Project Template that already includes a Nuget Package Reference?

I knew about templates.  Wish I had thought of it.  Thanks.
